# Voice recognition through a USB port

Tags: joystick

My name is Ismail, and I'm a 29-year-old guy with a physical disability which severely  limits my movements. I am able to access my computer by using a custom-made mini joystick which  I move with my lips and a touch switch near each thumb for left and right clicking. I also have a prototype gaming helmet which has four touch switches so that I can play games using my cheeks and eyebrows as well.

Lastly I use a voice recognition program called Game Commander 3 so that I can use my voice to handle the remaining keystrokes in games due to the fact that I cannot  physically use more than six switches and a joystick.

Now that you know my situation, I will explain my problem.

I have recently purchased an [I-PAC FS32](http://www.ultimarc.com/ipac1.html) gaming interface board that has been switch adapted for me so that I can connect my switches to it and play games on various gaming consoles, for example, PS2, PS3, Gamecube, etc., using various adapter cables. This board has 32 digital inputs as well as a [PS/2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PS/2_connector) and [USB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Serial_Bus) port. It's possible to connect a hardware keyboard to the USB port and play games. However, what I need is a program that will allow me to use Game Commander 3 (or any other voice recognition software) to send voice commands that act as keystrokes instead.

I basically need a window that just sits there and waits for keystrokes, then sends those keystrokes out through the USB port of my PC and into the board.

It would be good if the solution is portable as well, so I can run it on my PC and my laptop.

---

How can I send keyboard commands to a USB device? That is, as far as the USB device is concerned, a keyboard is connected to it.

Comment: It doesn't sound like you need to send keyboard commands... you just need to send them to the host PC which your software runs on.  The I-PAC is irrelevant, yes?

Answer (score 1):

Interesting problem - usually the computer is a 'USB Host' and you plug 'USB devices' into its USB inputs. Using the computer as if it is just a 'peripheral' (ie keyboard) really needs to send USB output. It's like driving data the wrong way up a one-way street.

Maybe the easiest way would be to use the computer (voice-operated) to operate switches on the inputs of the I-PAC ? Kind of clunky going back to moving parts such as relays, but even 'opto-isolators' would also protect I-PAC and computer from each other's voltages.

I would imagine voice-computer-switch systems must exist, but you are probably better-aware than I !

Velleman have a USB interface kit, No.K8055 that could be useful hardware. Not sure about software.

Comment: @OnlyMe thanks for your reply, I have sent this information to the man who deals with my computer access, hopefully this information would help him. i was thinking would it also be possible to use a usb to serial adapter and communicate with the board that way?